# Could someone tell me why this dashed box are shown on the dev tools and how to get rid of it?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: 1]

I can't align things because sometimes I encounter with these purple boxes. Could someone tell me why and how to get rid of it?

I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

This is called **flexbox overlay** and is a feature of the Chrome Developer Tools to [Inspect and debug CSS flexbox layouts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/flexbox/).

It is only a tool that helps developers visualize and debug the layout of elements on a web page that are using the Flexbox layout mode. It allows developers to see how elements are distributed along the main and cross axes, as well as their sizes and positions.

It's important to note that the Flexbox Overlay **does not affect how the elements in the DOM are rendered**. It is **purely a visual aid** for developers to see how their CSS Flexbox properties are affecting the layout of elements on the page.

In other words, the Flexbox Overlay is a helpful tool for debugging and fine-tuning the layout of a web page, but **it does not modify the actual layout of the elements in the DOM**.

See [Adjust the flexbox overlay color](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/flexbox/#layout) for additional control over this.

Answer (score 2):

To be more succinct than the currently existing answer, you can go to the `Layout` pane in devtools and turn off the options in the `Flexbox overlays` and `Grid overlays`.